# How is profile set automatically when running test cases?

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, autowired

I have a project which is dependent on a component developed by some different team; and that has declaration like this:

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
Class SomeClass {

  // code...
}
```

Now, when I use this in my project/module and when I try to use , it fails to auto-wire when I run test cases.

I am not able to understand how running a test cases activated "test" profile. Can anyone help me understand how profile gets set when we run a test case?

Comment: Just looking at the code of the test class should give you the answer. You haven't posted it, so we can't tell you how it actually does activate the profile. We can only make guesses.

Comment: @JBNizet: But in my test cases there is no mention of "test" or anything else; so not able to understand how this "test" profile gets activated. Any pointers which I can refer to?

Comment: Instead of having to guess, or list all the possibilities that could come to our minds, why don't you post your test class?

Comment: @JBNizet: I looked again in test class, and I see this --> @ActiveProfiles("test"); I think this is the reason why "test" profile gets activated. Is there a way to make the above class (in my post) to be able to be injectable ?

Comment: Well, yes. Remove `@Profile("!test")`: the only effect of this annotation is precisely to make this component unavailable when the test profile is activated. Adding this annotation and wanting to inject this class in a test where the test profile is activated is contradictory.

Comment: How are you invoking the test cases? if you use IDE there might be some spring profiles activated. Assuming you use maven, check for two things. 1. `settings.xml` to check if any profiles are declared. 2. When you're running `mvn clean test`, check if `-Dspring.profiles.active` is passed in